# How to make PHP echo data in script instead of the script tags?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a system that displays a product image connected to an entry in a form, to make it update automatically I'm using Javascript but it prints the literal  tags instead of the variable set in javascript.

I've tried using this method to turn my Javascript variable into a php variable, but I haven't found a way to do this properly. I also let it output towards regular HTML text and that worked properly, so I'm just stuck on how to read it in the file name.

HTML/PHP:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img src="elements/<?php echo 'fronten/' . $serie . '-' . $front . '-Front-' . $formaat; ?>.png" id="ladefront"/>
    <img src="elements/<?php echo 'kasten/' . $serie . '-' . '<script>document.writeln("kleur");</script>' . '-' . $formaat ?>.png" id="onderkast"/>
    <img src="elements/<?php echo 'bladen/' . $product . '-' . $formaat ?>.png" id="wastafelblad"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var kleur = document.getElementById("color").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = kleur;
}
```

The error it outputs is the following: `GET .../kasten/NEXXT-%3Cscript%3Edocument.writeln( 403 (Forbidden)` - so it puts the entire  content in the file name instead of what the script is supposed to echo. My expected output is supposed to be `.../kasten/NEXXT-(kleur)-60.png`.

Comment: So, where does the data actually come from? There's no connection between php and JS. php runs on the server, JS runs on the client. Also, stay away from `document.write`, as it dumps whatever you tell it to dump, _somewhere_ in the document, without any control over where that actually is.

Comment: What sense is what you have shown supposed to make in the first place … For PHP to be able to write a script element that should write `kleur` into the document, PHP would have to know that value, `kleur`, at this point already. But if it does that, you could output `kleur` directly in that place via PHP, and would not need any JavaScript to do that … Makes very little sense.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is utterly irrelevant here.

You can't put an element (and that includes a `<script>` element) inside an attribute value.

You'd need to either generate the entire `<img>` element with JavaScript, or dynamically change the `src` attribute with JavaScript after completing the element.